# Logarithmic series. Lower bound

Tags: complexity-theory

I am having some trouble, finding the lower bound for this series :

S = lg(n-2) + 2lg(n-3) + 3lg(n-4) + ... + (n-2)lg2.

The upper bound as I have figured out (and I explain below) is O (N^2 . lgN)
Could you help me in finding out the lower bound on this.

My proof for the upper bound goes as :

S = lg [ (n-2)* (n-3)^2 * (n-4)^3 *.. *2^(n-2) ]
  = O ( lg n^(1+2+3+..+(n-1) )
  = O ( n^2*log(n) )

**EDIT:**

Just a random thought. Can I assume the series to be closely approximated by Integral (xLogx), which happens to be O (X^2. lgX) ?? But this too, would give only an upper bound and not a lower bound.

Comment: Stack Overflow is for programming questions. Please consider http://math.stackexchange.com.

Comment: It's more of a Complexity analysis, which a good programmer must be aware of.

Comment: @n0nChun: I believe Greg meant that there's a difference between computer programming and computer science.

Comment: That's true, but if you want answers more specifically focused on your question, you may want to consider posting this question on a different site. Perhaps http://cstheory.stackexchange.com could be an option.

Comment: I agree, there. But, If the community thinks it needs to be migrated, then be it! :)

Comment: BUt I have seen a number of questions on complexity analysis (on Stackoverflow), and hence I thought of posting my question here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

lg(n-2) + 2lg(n-3) + 3lg(n-4) + ... + (n-2)lg2 > lg(n-2) + 2 lg(n-3) + ... + (n/2)log(n/2) = 

= lg [(n-2) * (n-3)^2 * ... * (n/2)^(n/2)] > lg[(n/2) * (n/2)^2 * ... * (n/2)^(n/2)] = 

= lg [(n/2)^(1+2+...+n/2)] = lg [ (n/2) ^ [(n^2)/4] = [(n^2)/4] * lg(n/2) = omega(n^2 * lgn)

Comment: Nicely done,Amit. And as a coincidence, my name is Amit too :)

Comment: @n0nchun: you welcome, the trick in these things is using only a part of the series where you can bound all elements to something convinient to you.